# Ruby lazy if statement with no operator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is it possible to do this in ruby?

```
variablename = true
if variablename
   puts "yes!"
end
```

Instead of this

```
variablename = true
if variablename == true
   puts "yes!"
end
```

Edit:
    also considering having:

```
variablename = 0 #which caused my problem
```

I can't get that to work. Is such a style of saying if possible? I'm learning ruby now, and it is possible in PHP but im not sure how to do it right in ruby

Comment: Saying something like "I can't get it to work" doesn't help anyone diagnose what you're doing wrong; as shown it works fine for me.

Comment: I had it my variablename = 0 and couldn't figure out why 'it wouldn't work'. From below I can see its that ruby considers 0 as true

Comment: I can see I set true there but here im asking if this coding style is possible. I appologize

Answer (score 9, accepted):

sure, it's possible

everything except `nil` and `false` is treated as true in ruby. Meaning:

```
var = 0
if var
  # true!
end

var = ''
if var
  # true!
end

var = nil
if var
  # false
end
```

Comment: Interesting. that '0' is what confused me

Comment: It not treated as `true` but just *truthy*, so only in statements that query for trutyiness (e.g.  `if` or `case`) it's equivalent. But if you compare truthy values with `true`you will still get non-equality.

Answer (score 3):

xdazz and Vlad are correct with their answers, so you would need to catch `0` separately:

```
variable = false if variable.zero?  # if you need 0 to be false
puts "yes!" if variable             # now nil, false & 0 will be considered false
```

Comment: A more "ruby" way would be `variable = false if variable.zero?`. Having said that, one should understand the limitations(?) of the language and do not use zero is such cases.

Comment: Thank you, updated my answer to reflect that. And you're right about design choices made in ruby, but if this was a business logic problem that need acting upon rather than a programming choice, it is appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible at all. In ruby, only `nil` and `false` is considered as false, any other value is true.